# Sum of a List using Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, input

I don't understand why "head" is undefined in the following code, I'm trying to use a Accumulate pattern to get the some of a list of numbers.

```
def sum(items):
    if (items == None): #base case
        return 0
    else:
        return head(items) + sum(tail(items))
def main():
    items = (input("give me a list"))
    print ("the sum of the list is", sum(items))

main()
```

Comment: You don't *have* a `head()` function defined. Was that perhaps to be supplied by your teacher?

Comment: The definition of the `tail` function is missing as well.  Is this the whole code?

Comment: Sure it wasn't pseudo code as opposed to Python?

Comment: YEa this is the whole code, so I need to define what head and tail is exactly in the list of numbers given?

Comment: So is your job to make functions head and tail? What are they supposed to do?

Comment: I just have to create a set of functions that will take in a list from an input function then take the sum of the listed numbers

Comment: Were you given the driver as well, or did you write that? `input` always returns a single string, which you would somehow need to parse into a list of integers for `sum` to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `head` and `tail` are being called by passing arguments to them (`items` is the argument to both), you should declare them as functions:

```
def head(items):
    # ...
    return ...

def tail(items):
    # ...
    return ...
```

**Note:**

- If this is a homework, then the problem statement should specify what are those functions supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum(items):
    if not items:
        return 0
    else:
        head = lambda x: x[0]
        tail = lambda x: x[1:]
        return head(items) + sum(tail(items))
```

Comment: Please explain and elaborate the answer.